# Is SonarQube package design widget removed? And what about Groovy?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

After upgrading to Sonarqube 4.5.1 the Package Design widget is no longer available.
Is this intentional?
Accessing the "Design" menu item still provides the data, however it is no longer available on my dashboard?

And I am right when suspecting the package design analysis is not at all available when analysing Groovy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package design widget has been merged into the file design widget. You can read more about this on the [SONAR-5712](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5712) ticket.

And indeed, the design analysis is currently provided only by the Java plugin.