# Is the dependency matrix (package design widget) removed from sonarqube?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0

After a while I installed sonarqube 5.6 today and wondered where the dependency matrix feature is.

I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27836810/is-sonarqube-package-design-widget-removed-and-what-about-groovy), but it is about sonarqube 4.5.

I also searched the update center to see if I must install a additional plugin now, but I had no success.

Does anyone know how to get the package design widget back?

Answer (score 4):

I just found the answer. Sadly the package design widget is not available anymore.

Since sonarqube 5.2...

> All design-related features were dropped

See http://www.sonarqube.org/sonarqube-5-2-in-screenshots/ section **Also worth noting**

> All design-related features were dropped in this version (see [SONAR-6553](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6553)  for details), including Package Tangle Index and related metrics.